# matching impedance transformer in old designs

Tags: transistors, transformer, impedance, matching

I want you to see my question from an "historical point of view"...

Building circuits that I found in magazines of the '60 I see a lot of interstage transformer between Ge transistor stages etc..
I understand why they are here but my question is.. why they use transformer so much in the old times? Maybe they want save component count (more expensive at time) in the impedance matching?

I was looking at
http://gfresources.it/eresources/karl_von_mueller_little_monster.html

Take a look at the SO-3 transformer (that I made myself...)

Answer (score 1):

These days transformers are big, heavy and expensive.  Back in the ‘60s they were relatively cheap, reliable and practical to make yourself.  Similarly a low-value capacitor could be made using some thin metal rolled up with paper.  Compared with purchasing an expensive transistor or valve/tube you can imagine that a designer would use transformers wherever it avoided using a more exotic component.  Furthermore, valves/tubes work well at high voltages while loudspeakers are convenient to make with low impedances and so designers would likely have considered an output transformer to be the norm.

Comment: Thank you, I add a picture to see the circuit.

Comment: Inter-stage transformers aren't big or heavy ... unless in comparison with 0603's...

Comment: That’s exactly the comparison I had in mind

Comment: It's important to note that transformers have not gotten bigger or more expensive; rather, alternatives to transformers have gotten smaller and cheaper while transformers mostly remained the same.

Answer (score 1):

Back in the day, most designers using PNP germaniums had become engineers using valves (vacuum tubes) for their circuits, and were now thrilled at the possibilities of this new low powered valve.

Valves more or less need transformers, and their size meant that a transformer wasn't an obvious space-hog, so these designers would have had component drawers and junk-boxes filled with transformers, and minds full of designs using them.

Miniaturisation and portability in those days meant getting rid of the large valve 'bottles' and their plug-in bases, the heat they produced, the low voltage high current battery needed for the cathode heaters, and the high voltage low current battery, or high voltage inverter, for the anode power.

Replacing the transformers with new circuit configurations to handle the impedance mismatch between stages would have to wait. Those new circuit configurations often involve extra transistors. They are cheap as chips these days, but back in they they were very expensive, and the best design was the one that used the fewest active devices.

There's a radio design that uses a transistor to amplify the RF before the detector. The detected audio is then routed back through the same transistor for further amplification. The complication and potential for instability is more than made up for by the saving of one transistor.

Comment: @user287001 maybe, it's sort of tangential to the subject of transformers, and it would need a proper citation before it went in.

Answer (score 1):

The actual gain that makes a weak antenna or microphone signal to well hearable loud sound is "the power gain". Increasing only voltage is not enough, signal current must also be increased or at least it shoudn't get reduced.

With old germanium alloy transistors the available power gain per transistor wasn't especially much if only transistors and RC circuits were used. The current gain was maybe only 15 and there was substantial useless AC conductance between the collector and emitter. Today Vce affects much less to the collector current if the operating point is in the allowed range.

Using a transformer between the stages made possible optimal matching for maximum power gain. The collector circuit needed certain load impedance (=transistor's internal AC resistance between C and E), but the next input wanted to see much lower source impedance for max power gain. A transformer with well selected N1:N2 solved the contradiction.

In 1950's a transformer was much cheaper than an extra transistor to compensate the gain reduction caused by poorly matched RC-circuit. The size was not seen as a problem. A transformer could well take only 1/4 cubic inches, which was nothing when compared to common valve constructions.